# NSCompoundPredicate construction

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nscompoundpredicate

Say I have this array of predicates in the `feedDays` array:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7ff7f3cd1040>(
    feedDay == 1,
    feedDay == 2,
    feedDay == 4
)
```

I need to AND it with this `statusPredicates` array:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7ff7f3cd1070>(
    is_neutered == 0 AND other_status == 0,
    is_neutered == 0 AND other_status == 1,
    is_neutered == 0 AND other_status == 2,
    is_neutered == 0 AND other_status == 3,
)
```

How can I combine these into one query? I assume I have to use NSCompoundPredicate but I can't figure out how to get it to AND two arrays of predicates together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that a combined predicate such as

```
feedDay == 1 && feedDay == 2 ...
```

would be **always false**.

Thus what you perhaps mean is to combine each predicate with the `neutered` condition so that **both** conditions are true (`and`), and combine these individual groups so that **either** of these are true (`or`).

If you combine the array with into one big compound with `and` it is bound to be always false. Assuming that the `neutered` condition is always the same,

```
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
  @[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"is_neutered = 0"],
    [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubPredicates:feedDays]]];
```

That's pretty ugly, right? So I propose that you create an array with the possible values for `feedDay` and use the simple

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
     @"is_neutered = 0 && feedDay in %@", allowedFeedDays]
```

Comment: Nice well thought out answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code -

```
NSMutableArray *allPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:feedDays];
[allPredicates addObjectsFromArray:statusPredicates];

NSCompoundPredicate *finalPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:allPredicates];
```

Comment: This isn't quite right - the array it produces looks like [a,b,c,[d,e,f]] not [a,b,c,d,e,f] - you are adding the second array in its entirety to the first array rather than adding its members one by one.

Comment: Yes - now returns the same as my answer. Although actually now I run the code, your original answer was ok - it seems NSCompoundPredicate is smart enough to handle nested arrays of predicates - apologies